# rateit.js tooltip in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have this which is working well:

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="difficulty" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                            Condition
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="difficulty" class="form-control select2">
                                {{#each difficultyLevels}}
                                    <option value="{{_id}}">{{level}}</option>
                                {{/each}}
                            </select>
                            <div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#difficulty" data-rateit-step="1"></div>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Helper:

```
difficultyLevels(){
        return DifficultyLevels.find({}, {sort: {"_id":1}});
    }
```

Now I would like to add a tooltip to each option (star). The text is the same {{level}} value. 
How can I do that in meteor 1.3?

I've seen this: [rateit tooltip](http://gjunge.github.io/rateit.js/examples/#ex_10) but still cannot make it work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Should be as easy as:

```
<option data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{level}}" value="{{_id}}">{{level}}</option>
```

And then in the JS:

```
$("#difficulty").tooltip();
```